# Google Maps Api: The map() function doesnt return Markers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

Im using an earthquake api  to fetch this [JsonData](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson) with "react-google-maps"([Doc](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#introduction)).
But somehow the Markers dont appear and I dont get why.

```
const url =
  "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson";

const Map = () => {
  const defaultCoordinate = { lat: -0.8962, lng: -91.4445 }; 

  const getMarkers = () => {
    FetchEarthquakeData(url).then(result => {
      console.log(result.features);                     //LOG1
      result.features.map(earthquake => (
        console.log(earthquake),                        //LOG2
        <Marker
          key={earthquake.id}
          position={{
            lat: earthquake.geometry.coordinates[1],
            lng: earthquake.geometry.coordinates[0]
          }}
        />
      ));
    });
  };

  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultCenter={defaultCoordinate} defaultZoom={8}>
      {getMarkers()}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
};

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
```

The first console.log (LOG1) returns the array from the JsonData. LOG 2 returns every single object of the array. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Delete LOG2 and the comma and it Will work

Comment: `getMarkers` doesn't return anything, and even it it did, you're trying to get the result of an async call synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `return` statement to `getMarkers` (and one to the `.then` callback). (But this isn't the only issue here, see after the following code block for more)

The issue is not that `.map` isn't returning anything, but that `getMarkers` is not returning the output of `.map`.

Updated `getMarkers`:

```js
const getMarkers = () => {
  return FetchEarthquakeData(url).then(result => {
    console.log(result.features);                     //LOG1
    return result.features.map(earthquake => (
      console.log(earthquake),                        //LOG2
      <Marker
        key={earthquake.id}
        position={{
          lat: earthquake.geometry.coordinates[1],
          lng: earthquake.geometry.coordinates[0]
        }}
      />
    ));
  });
};
```

**However** `getMarkers` is an asynchronous function, so you cannot use its output directly in a render function (or body of a functional component). Instead, you should store the data from `FetchEarthquakeData` in a state variable and then take from state when rendering. You can also add a loading state while fetching the earthquake data.

For example:

```js
const url =
  "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_day.geojson";

const Map = () => {
  const defaultCoordinate = { lat: -0.8962, lng: -91.4445 };

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [earthquakes, setEarthquakes] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      const result = await FetchEarthquakeData(url);
      console.log(result.features); // LOG1
      setEarthquakes(result.features);

      setIsLoading(false);
    })();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return "loading...";
  }

  const markers = earthquakes.map(earthquake => (
    console.log(earthquake), // LOG2
    <Marker
      key={earthquake.id}
      position={{
        lat: earthquake.geometry.coordinates[1],
        lng: earthquake.geometry.coordinates[0]
      }}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultCenter={defaultCoordinate} defaultZoom={8}>
      { markers }
    </GoogleMap>
  );
};

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
```

Note that here we separate the data fetching logic from the rendering logic and store the fetched data in the component's state, then just take the data from state when rendering.

Also the `useEffect` syntax may look a bit strange but it's only necessary because the callback passed to `useEffect` cannot be asynchronous, so we create an anonymous asynchronous function and invoke it immediately.

Comment: This fixes the return problem but it still won't work because, now `getMarkers` returns a `Promise` not an array of `Marker` components.

Comment: @Titus updated the answer, let me know how that goes

Comment: Thank you guys. I had the same idea with hooks. Im going to play around with the code.